# Text and div containing two other divs are not inline

Tags: html, css

Here's the jsfiddle I'm playing with: http://jsfiddle.net/kwAqu/12/

I need the images to be inline with the "info" div. I've tried a variety of things (made the info and image spans, removed the image from the div and put display: inline for the img tag itself).

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem? This is what I want it to look like (you can ignore the borders, etc):
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to put title and text over the image?

Comment: nope - I want them side by side. I have updated my question with what I want it to look like - thanks for the question to clarify :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize `float: left;` and assign the text class a `width` to enclose the `.info` `div`.

You'll also want to wrap the elements in a parent element to ensure the items align properly.  I created a `div` with the ID of `wrapper` in my demo.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class = "one">
        <div class = "image"><img src = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"></div>
        <div class = "info">
            <div class = "title">this is my title</div>
            <div class = "text">Hello this is what I'm trying to inline. but its not working! what's going on...?</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
 width: 600px;   
}

.image {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.info {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

Note: You can adjust the padding for the `.info` `div` accordingly, along with the width of the `wrapper` `div`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rm7Pg/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is

```
.image {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This will try to match up the image with the rest of the elements.

Read up on it as such places as:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align